# How to post Reflection.MethodBase by Service Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, reflection

I'm creating a Log system using a Backend (.Net C#) with Lucene engine and I'm logging every method request.

To do this, I create a Service Reference in the backend and one of the WebService method param is the Reflection.MethodBase.

In the Frontend, I have added the reference (the .Net created a Soap Client connector).
But, the method don't expects the Reflection.MethodBase, it expects another MethodBase class (TestLogger.RefLogger.MethodBase).

I think that the .Net creates a Clone class for each method param that is not a primitive.

The problem is, I cannot cast from Reflection.MethodBase to MyLooger.MethodBase, eg:

```
public static void addLog(MethodBase methodBase, object[] parameters, TestLogger.RefLogger.TipoLog tipoLog)
{
    TestLogger.RefLogger.WSLoggerSoapClient client = new TestLogger.RefLogger.WSLoggerSoapClient();
    client.AddLogNormal(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), parameters, tipoLog);
}
```

Here, it shows me that it cannot convert the types, even if I try a Cast:

```
(TestLogger.RefLogger.MethodBase)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()
```

So, I try to create a method to "convert" the objects, creating a new MyLogger.MethodBase and copy the values, but it has no constructor.

```
TestLogger.RefLogger.MethodBase mDest = new TestLogger.RefLogger.MethodBase();//CANNOT DO THIS
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to log the information of this method, you can retrieve this information in the FrontEnd, using the MethodBase.GetParameters :

```
String methodName
String[] parametersNames 
String[] parametersValues
```

To create the methodName you can use methodBase.DeclaringType.Namespace + "." + methodBase.DeclaringType.Name + "." + methodBase.Name .

To create the parametersNames use the MethodBase.GetParameters:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Then you can pass this parameters to your backend.

This types the web service will recognize.

Comment: This was the only solution I found. Tank you.